# Google fit offline - access token issue

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-fit

Hi Everyone i facing one strange issue from long time with few accounts while syncing google fit data for few users.

We have followed below document for offline-access of google fit - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

Step 1 - get access token (Here we are refreshing token as when require), In this step we are getting error

400 Bad Request POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Bad Request" }

```
public String getAccessToken(ThirdPartyAuthDto r) throws Exception {
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = getGoogleClient();
        // request token
        if (r.getRefreshToken() == null || (r.getRefreshToken() != null && r.getRefreshToken().length() == 0)) {
            GoogleTokenResponse activeUser = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(),
                    new JacksonFactory(), "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
                    clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(), clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
                    r.getServerAuthCode(), "").execute();

            r.setAccessToken(activeUser.getAccessToken());
            r.setTokenType(activeUser.getTokenType());
            r.setExpiresInSeconds(activeUser.getExpiresInSeconds());
            r.setRefreshToken(activeUser.getRefreshToken());
            r.setScope(activeUser.getScope());
            r.setLastRequestDate(new Date());
            r.setLastRequestSuccessDate(new Date(new Date().getTime() - (5 * 60000)));
            thirdPartyRepository.save(r);
            return activeUser.getAccessToken();
        } else {
            boolean tokenRequest = true;
            if (r.getLastRequestSuccessDate() != null
                    && new Date().before(new Date(r.getLastRequestSuccessDate().getTime() + r.getExpiresInSeconds() * 1000))){
                tokenRequest = false;
            }
            if(tokenRequest) {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = refreshAccessToken(r.getRefreshToken(), clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(), clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret());
                r.setAccessToken(tokenResponse.getAccessToken());
                r.setLastRequestSuccessDate(new Date(new Date().getTime() - (5 * 60000)));
                r.setExpiresInSeconds(tokenResponse.getExpiresInSeconds());
                thirdPartyRepository.save(r);
                return tokenResponse.getAccessToken();

            }else{
                return r.getAccessToken();
            }

        }

    }



public TokenResponse refreshAccessToken(String refreshToken, String clientId, String clientSecrets) throws IOException {
        TokenResponse response = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                refreshToken,
                clientId,
                clientSecrets)
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: can you check if your refresh token is expired

Comment: yes it's expired. Can we increase refresh token expiry date. right now it's 3599 second

Answer (score 0):

Getting invalid grant when using a refresh token normally means that the refresh token is expired or was revoked.

Possible reasons for expired refresh tokens.

1. the user has revoked your access
2. you have more then 50 outstanding refresh tokens for this user
3. The app is still in the testing phase which means refresh tokens expire after seven days.

Comment: yes i am getting issue at new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest() but i have checked user is not coming under all three point you raise here.  Expire time is only 3599 second coming from google not 7 days.

Comment: Is there way i can get help from google team?

Comment: Google rarely responds to these messages.  Its easer for them to just let me do it for free.

Comment: 3599  is the expire time of our access token.   Refresh token does not display a expire time.   Is your app still in test or is it in prodcution?